# Uniform Convergence and Integrals Relations

Tags: uniform-convergence

Prove that if $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$, then  $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_n(x)dx =\int f(x)dx$

I have tried using the definition of uniform convergence to state the fact that if $f_n$ uniformly converges to $f(x)$ then there $\exists N$ such that if $n\geq N \longrightarrow \mid f_n(x) - f(x) \mid < \epsilon$. Hence, $\mid \int (f_n(x)-f(x)) dx \mid \leq \int \mid f_n(x) - f(x) \mid dx < \int \epsilon dx = \epsilon x$

However I do not know how to continue the proof.

Answer (score 2):

This holds in general when we integrate over compact sets, in which your proof is done. If our space was not compact, we can get counter examples. We see that the functions $ \frac{1}{n}\chi_\mathbb{R} $ converge uniformly to $ f\equiv 0 $, but the integrals clearly do not converge.

If you are trying to show this for integrals over all of $ \mathbb{R} $, you need some other conditions on $ f_n $ (see the Dominated Convergence Theorem).

Comment: What would be the next step of the proof?

Comment: If we're working with Riemann integrals, then since they're defined only over intervals, we'd have that $ \int_a^b \varepsilon dx = \varepsilon(b-a) $, and taking $ \varepsilon $ small makes our integral small. If we're working with Lebesuge integrals, we're allowed to integrate over an arbitrary compact set, and the integral above would just be $ \varepsilon $ times the Lebesgue measure of the compact set (which is finite).